# How should I rewrite this code to not use feval?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I recently finished a homework set in my Applied Numerical Methods class and did alright on it.  However, my professor made a note to say I shouldn't use the feval() function because it's outdated.

I'm just wondering what I should use instead.

Here is the code in question

```
    %% function file
    function E=euler(f,a,b,ya,h)
        t=a:h:b;
        y(1)=ya;
        for i=1:length(t)-1
            y(i+1) = y(i) + h*(feval(f,t(i),y(i)));
        end
         t = t';
         y = y';
         E=t;
         plot(t,y)
         xlabel('t')
         ylabel('y') 
    end



    %% script file    

    f = @(y,t) (1-20*t*y)/(t^2); %solved for dy/dt

    x = 2:0.0001:10;
    exact = 1./(19.*x) - 524288./(19.*x.^20);
    figure(1)
    plot(exact);

    a = 2;
    b = 10;
    ya = 1;
    h = 0.01;
    figure(2)
    y1=euler(f, a, b, ya, h);

    h = 0.001;
    figure(3)
    y2=euler(f, a, b, ya, h);

    h = 0.0001;
    figure(4)
    y3=euler(f, a, b, ya, h);
```

How could I write this code to still properly evaluate the Euler function without using the feval function.

Comment: You could just use $f(t(i),y(i))$ if your input argument $f$ is defined as an inline function or a function handle.

Comment: I edited my question to include the parts of my code you mentioned.  So I can literally just get rid of the feval?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just be careful of the order $t,y$.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can see that

```
    [V,D] = feval('eig',A)
    [V,D] = eig(A)
```

Are equivalent.